# php array filter to filter an object from object of array

Tags: php, filter

I want to filter and Array of objects to get an object from it .for example i have a `$data` array like this

```
Array
(
  [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Country] => ALA Aland Islands
        [CountryCode] => AX
    )

  [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Country] => Afghanistan
        [CountryCode] => AF
    )

  [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Country] => Albania
        [CountryCode] => AL
    )

  [3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Country] => Algeria
        [CountryCode] => DZ
    )

  [4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [Country] => American Samoa
        [CountryCode] => AS
    )
 )
```

Im trying to filter the expected object like as:

```
$country_data = array_filter( $data, function($obj){
    return 'AF' == $obj->CountryCode;
});
```

but its not working.I am trying to achieve an array in end result containing that country , like this

```
Array(
    [Country] => Albania
    [CountryCode] => AL
)
```

Comment: Can you show us what end result you are trying to achieve please

Comment: In what way is it not working? The code you wrote should do exactly what you're describing.

Comment: dont know i am getting an empty array

Comment: What is the dump of, `$data` or something else?

Answer (score 0):

How about this way with `json_decode()`?

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($country_data), true);
print_r($array);
```

**Full demo code:**

```
<?php
$array = array
    (
    '0' => array
    (
        'Country' => 'ALA Aland Islands',
        'CountryCode' => 'AX'
    )
    ,
    '1' => array
    (
        'Country' => 'Afghanistan',
        'CountryCode' => 'AF'
    )
    ,
    '2' =>array
    (
        'Country' => 'Albania',
        'CountryCode' => 'AL'
    )
    ,
    '3' => array
    (
        'Country' => 'Algeria',
        'CountryCode' => 'DZ'
    )
    ,
    '4' => array
    (
        'Country' => 'American Samoa',
        'CountryCode' => 'AS'
    )
);
$data = json_decode(json_encode($array));
$country_data = array_filter( $data, function($obj){
    return 'AL' == $obj->CountryCode;
});
$array = json_decode(json_encode($country_data), true);
print_r($array);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/WUlCC

Comment: But my primary array is an array containing objects

Comment: @TickTwitch Yes, it should work with your primary array also, I just make that an array for DEMO purpose. You just need the 2 lines for what you want to achieve.

Comment: Not its not wokring when its object